# how to change calendar time to jalali(persian)

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using `syncfusion`  as a calendar package and i want to change its time to jalali(persian) how i am gonna do that? i already tried `localization` but that only changed the language ,

Comment: Maybe look at this https://pub.dev/packages/jalali_calendar or this https://pub.dev/packages/shamsi_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/issues/95), `syncfusion` does not support jalali calendar. You can try to change the package with [jalali_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/jalali_calendar).

```
import 'package:jalali_calendar/jalali_calendar.dart';

Future _selectDate() async {
    String picked = await jalaliCalendarPicker(context: context); // نمایش خروجی به صورت شمسی
   //  await jalaliCalendarPicker(context: context,convertToGregorian: true); // نمایش خروجی به صورت میلادی
    if (picked != null) setState(() => _value =picked.toString());
    print(_value);
  }
```

Comment: i wanted to create a event calendar like syncfusion calendar to add event to a time if it does not support jalali it is impossible to create somthing like that with other calendars anyway thanks for your help